# Read exchange email Oauth2 in java

Tags: java, azure, email, oauth-2.0

I have discovered that basic authentication to email account no longer works, when using java.mail library. It seems that an OAuth2 based authentication is needed. I need help in defining the actual steps. I have created a sample app in Azure and granted the IMAP, POP and SMTP permissions to it, but I don't know what are the next steps, how to actually tell my email reader (in Java code) that it should use this app and actually connect to the email inbox. The email server is a Microsoft Exchange server.

Comment: [Access to Office365 mailbox for a Java application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/843875/access-to-office365-mailbox-for-a-java-application.html), [JavaMail OAuth2 Support](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2) and [Setting up Microsoft Azure mailboxes for OAuth 2.0 authorization](https://docs.genesys.com/Documentation/ESEmail/latest/Admin/EmSMailAzure)

Comment: That sure helps. I was able to create a sample app and get a response that contains an idToken with a tokenValue that looks like a JWT token. Not sure if this is the access token or refresh token though, because when trying to use this value instead of password for email store connect, it's not working. Maybe a more into details actual example would be more helpful? Microsoft actually spams you with tons of information and it's hard to translate this theory into practice.